# ST_Intersects in postgis

Tags: postgis

My version : postgres 8.4.1/postgis 1.4.0

I want to perform a simple spatial join with the following query :

```
SELECT code_insee, nom, id_canton, lib_canton
FROM localisants.alca_toponyme_commune
LEFT JOIN localisants.alca_pseudo_cantons 
ON ST_Intersects(alca_pseudo_cantons.shape,alca_toponyme_commune.shape);
```

The type of geometry is POINT for alca_toponyme_commune and
MULTIPOLYGON for alca_pseudo_cantons.
Both tables are planned in EPSG:2154.

In my result, the join fields (id_canton, lib_canton) are empty.

Is there a problem in my query?

Comment: You didn't specify the schema name (localisants) for ST_Intersection parameters. Did you set the search_path? If you use LEFT JOIN and the cantons don't contain any points you can get empty columns. Try inner join and if you get 0 rows, the two data set do not overlap at all.

Comment: Could you give a geometry example? What geometry types are registered for your geometry columns within geometry_columns?

Comment: I specify the schema name without success.

Comment: The two layers overlap and are in EPSG: 2154.

Comment: I have : type POINT and a type MULTIPOLYGON.